# does this GADT actually have type role representational

Tags: haskell, gadt

This data type can have `type role HCons' representational representational`, which allows using `coerce` to add or remove newtypes applied to the elements, without needing to traverse the list.

```
data HNil' = HNil'
data HCons' a b = HCons' a b
```

However the syntax for those lists is not as nice as those with the following GADT

```
data HList (l::[*]) where
    HNil  :: HList '[]
    HCons :: e -> HList l -> HList (e ': l)
```

I have a class to [convert between these two representations](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/HList-0.3.4.1/docs/Data-HList-HList.html#t%3aConvHList), such that `Prime (HList [a,b]) ~ HCons' a (HCons' b HNil')`. Does that class make

```
coerceHList :: Coercible (Prime a) (Prime b) => HList a -> HList b
coerceHList = unsafeCoerce
```

safe?

Comment: FWIW, yes, I think so. But I don't know enough about the internals of roles to actually make a convincing argument. Your example seems to be another case where the current role system is not quite expressive enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think the existence of a conversion on its own is enough. For example, the following also lets me convert between a GADT and a coercible pair of types, but it certainly wouldn't be safe to directly coerce the GADT:

```
newtype Age = Age Int

data Foo a where
   I :: Bool -> Int -> Foo Int
   A :: Age -> Bool -> Foo Age

class ConvFoo a where
   toFoo :: (Bool, a) -> Foo a
   fromFoo :: Foo a -> (Bool, a)

instance ConvFoo Int where
   toFoo (b, i) = I b i
   fromFoo (I b i) = (b, i)

instance ConvFoo Age where
   toFoo (b, a) = A a b
   fromFoo (A a b) = (b, a)
```

I could also trivially define an `UnFoo` type function similar to `Prime`.

I think the key difference between the two examples is that in mine, `Age` and `Int` do have the same representation, whereas in yours `'[]` and `e':l` don't have the same representation.

So there's still a case for saying, as you suggest in the title, that `l` has type role representational, because it's kind of obvious that `HList l1` and `HList l2` have the same representations if `l1` and `l2` have the same representations.

However since in theory representations are implementation-dependent, I don't think you can ever consider this absolutely safe until GHC accepts it directly.

Comment: I'm not so sure about "it's kind of obvious that HList l1 and HList l2 have the same representations if l1 and l2 have the same representations". We could write `HCons :: (el ~ (e ': l)) => e -> HList l -> HList el`. Then it is possible ghc stores something for `el ~ (e ': l)` that references the original `e, el, l` types, and not the ones that are currently in the constructor?

Comment: Even then, every `HCons` would still have the same surface representation as every other `HCons`, wouldn't it? So if `e` and `HList l` also had the same representations then the whole `HCons` would.

Comment: I think the key point is that `':` and `'[]` are concrete types that must be different, so there's no risk of confusing `HCons` and `HNil`. I'm not at all sure how to formulate the condition precisely though!