# Understanding this definition of HList

Tags: haskell, types, ghc, type-level-computation, data-kinds

I'm relatively new to Haskell, and I'm trying to understand one of the definitions of [HList](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/HList-0.4.1.0/docs/Data-HList-HList.html).

```
data instance HList '[] = HNil
newtype instance HList (x ': xs) = HCons1 (x, HList xs)
pattern HCons x xs = HCons1 (x, xs)
```

I have a couple specific questions:

- What is the `'[]` and `(x ': xs)` syntax I'm seeing? It almost looks like it's pattern matching on variadic type parameters, but I have never seen this syntax before, nor am I familiar with variadic type parameters in Haskell. I would guess this is part of [GHC's Type Families](https://wiki.haskell.org/GHC/Type_families), but I don't see anything about this on the linked page, and it's rather hard to search syntax in Google.
- Is there any point in using a `newtype` declaration with a tuple (instead of a `data` declaration with two fields) besides avoiding boxing of `HCons1`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First, you are missing part of the definition: the `data family` declaration itself.

```
data family HList (l :: [*])
data instance HList '[] = HNil
newtype instance HList (x ': xs) = HCons1 (x, HList xs)
```

This is called a [`data family`](https://wiki.haskell.org/GHC/Type_families#Detailed_definition_of_data_families) (available under the `TypeFamilies` extension).

```
pattern HCons x xs = HCons1 (x, xs)
```

This is a bidirectional pattern (available under the `PatternSynonyms` extension).

> What is the `'[]` and `(x ': xs)` syntax I'm seeing?

When you see `'` marks in front of constructors, it is to denote their [promoted type-level counterparts](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#overview). As a syntactic convenience, [promoted lists and tuples](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#promoted-list-and-tuple-types) also just need the extra tick (and we still get to write `'[]` for the empty type-level list and `':` for the type level cons. All of this is available through the `DataKinds` extension.

> Is there any point in using a `newtype` declaration with a tuple (instead of a data declaration with two fields) besides avoiding boxing of `HCons1`?

Yes, it is to make sure that `HList` has a representational [role](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/Roles), which means you can coerce between `HList`s<sup>1</sup>. This is a bit too involved to explain in just an answer, but here is an example of where things don't go as we want when we have

```
 data instance HList (x ': xs) = HCons x (HList xs)
```

instead of the `newtype instance` (and no pattern). Consider the following `newtype`s which are representationally equivalent to `Int`, `Bool`, and `()` respectively

```
newtype MyInt = MyInt Int
newtype MyBool = MyBool Bool
newtype MyUnit = MyUnit ()
```

Recall we can use [`coerce`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Data-Coerce.html) to wrap or unwrap these types automatically. Well, we'd like to be able to do the same thing, but for a whole `HList`:

```
ghci> l  = (HCons 3 (HCons True (HCons () HNil))) :: HList '[Int,   Bool,   ()]
ghci> l' = coerce l                               :: HList '[MyInt, MyBool, MyUnit]
```

This works with the `newtype instance` variant, but not the `data instance` one because of the roles. (More on that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24222552/does-this-gadt-actually-have-type-role-representational).)

---

<sup>1</sup> technically, there is no role for a `data family` as a whole: the roles can be different for each `instance`/`newtype` - here we only really need the `HCons` case to be representational, since that's the one that gets coerced. [Check out this Trac ticket](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/8177).

Comment: Does the `(l :: [*])` mean a type parameter `l` constrained to kind `[*]`?

Comment: @Textfield Exactly! A type parameter that has is a promoted list of types. Come to think of it, getting that to compile may need turning on `KindSignatures` too and possibly importing `Data.Kind` too... Just do whatever GHC advises you to. :)

Answer (score 2):

`'[]` and `(x ': xs)` are syntax for type-level lists in the sense that the [`DataKinds` language extension allows promoting types to kinds and constructors to types](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#datatype-promotion); i.e. if `k` is some kind, then `'[k]` is also a kind, and `'[]` is a type of kind `'[k]`, and if `t :: k` and `ts :: '[k]`, then `t ': ts :: '[k]`. Everything gets shifted by one.

So in `HList (x ': xs)`, `x` and `xs` match two types: `x` matches a "normal" type of kind `*` (e.g. `Int`) and `xs` matches another type-level list of kind `'[*]`. The right-hand side defines a (`newtype`) datatype that has a constructor `HCons1` with a parameter of type `(x, HList xs)`.

As an example, we can have

```
HCons1 (1, HCons1 (True, HNil)) :: HList '[Int, Bool]
```

Or, using the pattern synonym:

```
1 `HCons` True `HCons` HNil :: HList '[Int, Bool]
```

I don't have a good answer to your second question regarding why it's represented as a newtype with a tuple.