# Extensible records (I think)

Tags: haskell

What I roughly want is this:

```
data A = ...
data B = ...
data C = ...

class HasA t where
  getA :: t -> A

class HasB t where
  getB :: t -> B

class HasC t where
  getC :: t -> C
```

So I can do something like this (pseudocode follows):

```
a :: A
b :: B

x = mkRecord { elemA a, elemB b }
y = mkRecord { elemB b, elemA a }

-- type of `x` == type of `y`
```

Naturally, only the appropriate `get` functions work, in the above case `getA` and `getB`.

I'd also like the following functions

```
slice :: Subset a b => a -> b
slice x = -- just remove the bits of x that aren't in type b.

add :: e -> a -> a ++ e
add e x = -- add an element to the "record" (compile error if it's already there)
```

I feel like this is not a new problem so perhaps a resolution for this already exists. Note that I don't require the solution to be extensible, the amount of types I need to deal with is finite and known, but of course and extensible one wouldn't hurt.

I've found a couple of packages that seem to be in the field of what I'm looking for, namely [HList](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/HList) and [extensible](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/extensible) (perhaps extensible is better because I want my records unordered). I got a bit lost in the Hackage docs so I'd like just some sample code (or a link to some sample code) that roughly achieves what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

This is exactly what `HList` is good for. However, since I don't have the right setup to test something with the `HList` package right now (and besides, it has [more confusing data definitions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41135212/3072788)), here is a minimal example of `HList` that uses `singletons` for the type-level list stuff.

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds, TypeOperators, GADTs,TypeFamilies, UndecidableInstances,
    PolyKinds,  FlexibleInstances, MultiParamTypeClasses
  #-}

import Data.Singletons
import Data.Promotion.Prelude.List

data HList (l :: [*]) where
  HNil :: HList '[]
  HCons :: x -> HList xs -> HList (x ': xs)
```

The `add` function is the simplest: it is just `HCons`:

```
add :: x -> HList xs -> HList (x ': xs)
add = HCons
```

Something more interesting is combining two records:

```
-- Notice we are using `:++` from singletons
combine :: HList xs -> HList ys -> HList (xs :++ ys)
combine HNil xs = xs
combine (x `HCons` xs) ys = x `HCons` (xs `combine` ys)
```

Now, for your `get` function, you need to dispatch based on the type-level list. To do this, you need an overlapping type class.

```
class Has x xs where
  get :: xs -> x

instance {-# OVERLAPS #-} Has x (HList (x ': xs)) where
  get (x `HCons` _) = x

instance Has x (HList xs) => Has x (HList (y ': xs)) where
  get (_ `HCons` xs) = get xs
```

Finally, we can use `Has` to define a similar `Subset` class. Same idea as before.

```
class Subset ys xs where
  slice :: xs -> ys

instance Subset (HList '[]) (HList xs) where
  slice _ = HNil

instance (Get y (HList xs), Subset (HList ys) (HList xs)) =>
           Subset (HList (y ': ys)) (HList xs) where
  slice xs = get xs `HCons` slice xs
```

---

As you mention in parens, the simple `HList` form does not ensure you have only *one* of any type of field (so `get` just returns the first field, ignoring the rest). If you want uniqueness, you can just add a constraint to the `HList` constructor.

```
data Record (l :: [*]) where
  Nil :: Record '[]
  Cons :: (NotElem x xs ~ 'True) => x -> Record xs -> Record (x ': xs)
```

However, defining `Subset` using `Record` looks like it involves some proofs. :)