# Future of roles for GADT-like type variables?

Tags: haskell, types, ghc, roles, gadt

A [question from yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41135212/3072788) had a definition of `HList` (from the [`HList`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/HList-0.4.1.0/docs/Data-HList-HList.html) package) that uses data families. Basically:

```
data family HList (l :: [*])
data instance HList '[] = HNil
newtype instance HList (x ': xs) = HCons1 (x, HList xs)

pattern HCons x xs = HCons1 (x, xs)
```

instead of the usual (IMO more elegant and intuitive) GADT definition

```
data HList (l :: [*]) where
  HNil :: HList '[]
  HCons :: x -> HList xs -> HList (x ': xs)
```

This is because the data family version lets us coerce (we only get to coerce the `HList (x ': xs)` case since it is a `newtype instance`, but that is enough), while the GADT infers only a nominal role for `l` (thus blocking any coercion). ([My answer to the mentioned question has a concrete example of this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41135693/3072788).)

The failings of the role system for GADTs with respect to `HList` are discussed in this [two year old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24222552/does-this-gadt-actually-have-type-role-representational?noredirect=1&lq=1). Basically, GHC automatically marks any "GADT-like" type variable as nominal.

Given that some time has passed since then and [there is talk of making roles more flexible around type/data families](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/8177), is there any path forward (i.e. some existing idea, some open Trac ticket, anything really) for checking more interesting roles in GADTs (like `HList`)? Are there some fundamental limitations here with GADTs or the interplay of `DataKinds` and roles? What would need to be implemented/created for this to work?

Answer (score 1):

Author of the roles system here. I'm aware of no ideas that will move us forward in this direction. The problem is that we'd need to check a delicate property in order to ensure that the coercion is safe. Specifically, we want to be able to coerce e.g. `HList [Age, Int, String]` to `HList [Int, Age, String]` but not to `HList [String, String, Int]` (or an `HList` with something other than three elements). (I'm assuming `newtype Age = MkAge Int` here.) Pulling this off would require some Very Glorious role-like system -- capable of describing exactly what coercions would be safe for such a GADT -- and I don't know of any work toward creating such a system.

The reason the data family approach works is that GHC can see that `HList [Age, Int, String]` is really the same as `(Age, (Int, (String, HList '[])))`, and then it knows tuples well enough to do the rest of the work.

Sorry to have no encouragement here, but this seems well beyond what we can do now.